# Salt Stack: Requiring packages installed before formula executed

Tags: devops, salt-stack, system-administration

This is more of a clarification request.

I have two formulas that rely on a bunch of packages being installed by the `init.sls` formula before they're run.

At the moment I have something like the below. I was wondering if anyone could confirm this is the correct approach, or whether someone could indeed offer a better approach.

`init.sls`

```
install_packages:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
        - foo
        - bar
    - require_in:
      - sls: brrap
      - sls: blah
```

So would doing this ensure that the above packages are installed before brrap.sls and blah.sls are executed?

Thanks

Comment: Looks good from my point of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using the `require_in` requisite in your example will ensure the packages are installed before `brrap.sls` and `blah.sls` are executed.

All of the `_in` requisites work in the same way: they result in a normal requisite in the targeted state. The `require_in` statement is particularly useful when assigning a require in separate sls files.

As long as the `brrap.sls` and `blah.sls` states do not need to be aware of the additional components (*the `foo` and `bar` packages*) that require it when it is set up, your configuration is fine. If the `brrap.sls` and `blah.sls` states do require the `foo` and `bar` packages to be installed in all the cases, it might be a more straightforward solution to create a `require` requisite from the `brrap.sls` and `blah.sls` states.

Take for instance the following state `http.sls`:

```
httpd:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: httpd
  service.running:
    - name: httpd
```

On some of your minions you might want to use the `http.sls`, and on others you might want to use the `http.sls` **and** the `php.sls` states:

```
include:
  - http

php:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: php
    - require_in:
      - service: httpd
```

Now the httpd server will only start if php is verified to be installed.

Take a look at the [requisites and other global state arguments](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#direct-requisite-and-requisite-in-types) documentation for the full example.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough clarification

Comment: Note require_in on entire sls files is [broken until Nitrogen](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/22852) release.